# Can Robocopy be configured to only log the “errors”?

Tags: windows, robocopy

Can Robocopy be configured to only log the “errors”?

On a large copy job, I’m really only interested in knowing what files were NOT copied.

Comment: Try using `/NFL /NDL /NP`.

Comment: Did you try logging to a file and feeding that file to grep (or simply "find") ?

Comment: /NDL did remove the verbose output and show only errors & copy progress

Answer (score 1):

If you add `/LOG:log.txt` to the end, you generate a file with the logs.

**And addiotional info:**

[image]

Good look!